# create Django form class with dynamic number of CharFields

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm having problem of creating a dynamic class form that contains a list of CharFields.
I'm able to create a normal class with dynamic keys values as below. but when I change the values to be a CharFields. it doesn't work. What's wrong with the form?

=========Normal class===========

> class DynamicClass(forms.Form):

> ```
> def __init__ (self, data):
>         self.data =data
>         for key in self.data.keys():
>                 self.__setattr__(key, self.data[key])
> ```

> my_class = DynamicClass({"HOSTNAME": 'Router_Hostname: ', "IP": 'IP_ADDRESS:'})

> print (my_class.HOSTNAME)

> output --> Router_Hostname:

> print (my_class.IP)

> output--> IP_ADDRESS:

=========Form class===========

> class DynamicForm(forms.Form):

> ```
> def __init__ (self, data):
>         self.data =data
>         for key in self.data.keys():
>                 self.__setattr__(key, forms.CharField(label = self.data[key]))
> ```
>
> my_form = DynamicForm ({"HOSTNAME": 'Router_Hostname: ', "IP": 'IP_ADDRESS:'})

> print (my_form.as_table)

> error output-->

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "~/automation/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 137, in **repr**
> if self._errors is None:
> AttributeError: 'DynamicForm' object has no attribute '_errors'

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved
firstly, i shouldn't use "label" to set initial value for CharField(). Instead, use 'initial' keyword.
2nd, missing `super(DynamicForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

finally a working solution:

```
class DynamicForm(forms.Form):
def __init__ (self, data,  *args, **kwargs):
    super(DynamicForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.data = data
    for key in self.data.keys():
        self.fields[key] = forms.CharField(initial = self.data[key])
```